# compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle after upgrading flutter 3.19.0

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

**After upgrading Flutter version ``3.19.0 getting this error I'm stuck 8 hour in this issue but not resolve anybody can tell me how to fix it?**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I'm trying from  `compileSdk 33` to  `compileSdkVersion 33` and adding plugins id `"com.android.application"` top of `app/build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CompileSdkVersion is deprecated, please use the new compileSdk instead.

```
android {
   namespace "your.package.name"
   compileSdk flutter.compileSdkVersion (or any SDK like 33 or 34)
```